# Skip password for Azure MFA with SSH

Tags: ssh, azure

When configuring SSHD on a Linux server to use Azure MFA via RADIUS, is it possible to configure the MFA server to not ask for a first factor?

My use case is that I want public key authentication followed by Microsoft Authenticator. However it seems Azure MFA prompts for the Windows password every time, rendering the public key authentication useless.

I am using the following as a guide:

[Secure SSH access using Azure Multi-Factor Authentication](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/33678.secure-ssh-access-using-azure-multi-factor-authentication.aspx)

Thanks.

Comment: I suppose you are using AD accounts for the tests.
Have you tried local account with pub key access ?

Answer (score 0):

Once you have updated the SSHD config the authentication bit is all done on the RADIUS server.

The question you are looking for is, **`"Can i configure RADIUS to do individual certificate (SSH Key) authentication?"`**

As far as i know you cannot.

Comment: In fact, I am looking for "Can I configure RADIUS to do individual token/push authentication?" since the primary factor - pubkey - would already have been validated by sshd.